# Change Image transition with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I have got already the css and the html structure, but the javascript it is not working, and the effect is nice, I want to get this image effect: http://www.ustream.tv/new (the blue one)

I have already tried but i dont get it: http://redzer.com.mx/img.html

What am i doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ustream is not defined.`[**Using the console**](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ustream={};
ustream.timing={};
ustream.timing.firstByte=(new Date()).getTime();
</script>
```

EDIT

After that $ is missing, it's probably `jQuery`. Import it than try

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT 2

You are missing this :

```
<script src="http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/packed/l10n/en_us/v6_home:13721527971.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

EDIT 3
Import this :

```
<script src="http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/packed/l10n/en_us/v6_header_static_framework:13718193491.js" type="text/javascript">
```

You can use `FireBug` plugin in FF to see console errors

Comment: The background still not moving

Comment: Same, is not working :S I think thats its a variable because it changes when you modify the class in `<div id="promo" class="(state1, state2, state3 or state4)">`

Comment: remove jquery from my example and add this http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/packed/l10n/en_us/header_libs_v6_home:13720735331.js

Comment: Sorry I can't, there is a lot of work for that. Simpler solution will be to create your custom animation of that elements. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp